# Compose : How do I get the bottom navigation bar height for Material3?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to get the Material3 Bottom NavigationBar height using code

[image]

I searched and couldn't find how, i had a workaround of tracing the official code to a`private` and `internal obeject` of value `80.dp`. But i feel using `80.dp` in my code might not be the best approach, is there any better way...?

Comment: What's the final goal?

Comment: is there a better way to get the height :- could be used for content padding(bottom) amongst others

Answer (score 2):

You may find something useful to position your screen content with the help of the `PaddingValues` lambda offered by [`Scaffold`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/material#screen-content). It also has a bottom bar slot and has some state and position smarts.

Answer (score -1):

You can manipulate the height of this component using Modifier.height() in the NavigationBar. But please take notice that this will most likely cause the labels to overlap your icons if you decrease this height. For a bottom bar without labels, it works fine.

```
NavigationBar(modifier = Modifier.height(<your_height_here>)) {...}
```